# Elasticssearch search by substring works not correct

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

This is my config:

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        website:
            settings:
                index:
                     analysis:
                        analyzer:
                            my_analyzer:
                                type: custom
                                tokenizer: lowercase
                                filter   : [my_ngram]
                        filter:
                            my_ngram:
                                type: "nGram"
                                min_gram: 2
                                max_gram: 50
            types:
                company:
                    mappings:
                        #cmpName: { boost: 10}
                        cmpName: { boost: 10, type: string, analyzer: my_analyzer}
                    persistence:
                        identifier: cmpCode
                        driver: orm # orm, mongodb, propel are available
                        model: Catalog\WebBundle\Entity\ComCompany
                        provider:
                        listener:
                        finder:
```

What is wrong:

I have 3 record:

- LANGAMA, UAB plastikiniai langai
- AUKŠTAITIJOS LANGAI, UAB LOSTIKOS
- LANGAI, UAB

If I search "langai" it found all 3 result
If I try search "lang" it not found nothinw, WHY ?

What is wrong with my config, that search not work by substring ?

Comment: did you try adding wild cards by searching for "\*lang\*"?

Comment: Can you paste the output of 'curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/INDEX_NAME/_analyze?analyzer=flat&pretty' -d 'langai' here. Please use after substituting the INDEX_NAME token.